# Quotes problems inside echo

Tags: php, echo, quotes, double-quotes

I want to put this line into **echo** :

```
<a title=\"Details\" href=\"produit.php?Id_Produit=".$row["id_produit"]."\"><img src=\"photos_produits/".$row["image_url"]."\" /></a>
```

How can I do this please, I have problem with quotes !

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you missed several.  note I find it a lot easier to parse single quotes for php, and use the double quotes for the html, and there's no need to escape them

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it might work

```
echo "<a title='Details' href='produit.php?Id_Produit=" .$row["id_produit"]. "'"><img src='photos_produits".$row["image_url"]. "'/></a>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the easiest, [`heredoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

```
$str = <<<ANCHOR
<a title="Details" href="produit.php?Id_Produit={$row["id_produit"]}"><img src="photos_produits/{$row["image_url"]}"></a>
ANCHOR; // make sure there is no extra spaces at the start of this line

echo $str;
```